# How to filter values corresponding to specific keys in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need to separate out the values in an object by category, which is visible from the key names of the object. Here is part of what the object may look like:

```
const values = {
        RM1: 'Rarely',
        RM2: 'Often',
        RM3: 'Sometimes',
        RM4: 'Consistently',
        CM1: 'Rarely',
        CM2: 'Never',
        CM3: 'Sometimes',
        CM4: 'Sometimes',
        CO1: 'Often',
        CO2: 'Often',
        CO3: 'Often',
        CO4: 'Sometimes'
}
```

The categories are RM, CM, CO, etc. I wrote a function that will filter out the categories (`answers` is a larger object that `values` is a part of):

```
const categorizeAnswers = (answers) =>{
  const valueNames = Object.keys(answers.values);
  const values = Object.values(answers.values);
  const getCategoryList = category => valueNames.filter(value => {
    return value.includes(category);
  })
  const RM = getCategoryList("RM");
  const CM = getCategoryList("CM");
  const CO = getCategoryList("CO");
}
```

But now I'm not sure how to get the values that correspond to those categories. So for `RM`, I want an array like: `['Rarely', 'Often', 'Sometimes', 'Consistently']`. And likewise for the other categories.

Any ideas? I feel like this is really quite simple and I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use map on the array of categories to get their values in an array like this:

```
const RM = getCategoryList("RM").map((key) => answers.values[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the categories dynamically based on the non–digit part of the property name, then add them to an initially empty object all in one *reduce* call. That way the categories aren't hard coded (but need to fit the same naming pattern):

```js
var values = {
        RM1: 'Rarely',
        RM2: 'Often',
        RM3: 'Sometimes',
        RM4: 'Consistently',
        CM1: 'Rarely',
        CM2: 'Never',
        CM3: 'Sometimes',
        CM4: 'Sometimes',
        CO1: 'Often',
        CO2: 'Often',
        CO3: 'Often',
        CO4: 'Sometimes'
}

function getCategories(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce(function(acc, key){
    var p = key.replace(/\d+/,'');
    acc[p]? acc[p].push(data[key]) : acc[p] = [data[key]];
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));
}

console.log(getCategories(values));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas? I feel like this is really quite simple and I'm missing
>   something obvious.

You are using a wrong variable `valuesNames`, make it `valueNames` which you had initialized in the same method before

```
var categorizeAnswers = (answers) =>{
  const valueNames = Object.keys(answers.values);
  const values = Object.values(answers.values);
  const getCategoryList = category => valueNames.filter(value => { //notice the change from valuesNames to valueNames 
    return value.includes(category);
  })

  const RM = getCategoryList("RM");
  console.log(RM);
  const CM = getCategoryList("CM");
  const CO = getCategoryList("CO");
}
```

Also, Just like `"RM1".includes("RM")` is `true`,  `"ARM1".includes("RM")` is also `true`

Use `indexOf`

```
  const getCategoryList = category => valueNames.filter(value => { 
    return value.indexOf(category) == 0;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check with [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for uniuque values

```
const getCategoryList = category =>
        [...new Set(valuesNames.filter(v => v.startsWith(category))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for..in` to iterate the object  & `indexOf` to check if the key name has the passed string

```js
var values = {
  RM1: 'Rarely',
  RM2: 'Often',
  RM3: 'Sometimes',
  RM4: 'Consistently',
  CM1: 'Rarely',
  CM2: 'Never',
  CM3: 'Sometimes',
  CM4: 'Sometimes',
  CO1: 'Often',
  CO2: 'Often',
  CO3: 'Often',
  CO4: 'Sometimes'
}

function getValues(keyName) {
  var valArray = [];
  for (let keys in values) {
    if (keys.indexOf(keyName) !== -1 && valArray.indexOf(values[keys]) === -1) {
      valArray.push(values[keys])

    }

  }
  return valArray;
}
console.log(getValues('CO'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much compact solution using ES5.

```
const getCategoryList = (category) => {
  const categories = [].concat(Object.keys(answers.values).filter((value) => value.includes(category)));
  const values = [].concat(categories.map((value) => answers.values[value]));
  return [categories, values]
}

const [ categories, values ] = getCategoryList('RM');
console.log(categories, values)
```